# Gevent hub raises exception on pool

Tags: python, gevent

Running gevent pool gives me the following exception on `join`:

> return greenlet.switch(self)
>
> gevent.hub.LoopExit: ('This operation would block forever', Hub at 0x105cbd190 select default pending=0 ref=0)

Code is:

```
    queue = gevent.queue.Queue(items=range(5))
    pool = gevent.pool.Pool(3)
    pool.map(self.foo_index, queue)
    pool.join(raise_error=True)
```

The error seems to occur before `join` is called during `map`. Oh no wait, an exception is raised immediately which must come from `join`: this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Using [map_async](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html#gevent.pool.Group.map_async) on your sample code did resolved the issue on my side. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If I use that it never starts the coroutines: `2016-07-19 17:53:05,648 - INFO    - [loader.py:foo] queue: <Queue queue=deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])>`
`2016-07-19 17:53:05,649 - INFO    - [loader.py:foo] done`

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because of the `gevent.queue.Queue` object. I replaced it with a default list and now it works. Not sure why the Queue is a problem, as it seems to be an iterable.